# Android connection to http server: Eclipse throws exception about localhost even though I state my online server?

Tags: java, android, mysql, url, connection

I'm working on an android Project in eclipse and I have the following Problem.

Why does the following code throw the exception

```
W/System.err(5354): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Even though my variable AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS is NOT localhost but an online Server address, something like http://myserver.com/folder/.

The code sample which should connect to my Server:

```
url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);
HttpURLConnection connection;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
```

The exception is thrown in the line with `PrintWriter`. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dnt use localhost,Use Ip address.

e.g `String URL="http://127.0.0.1(thats your ip):1802(thats your port)/.."`

Comment: Thats the strange Thing, Im using url = new URL(http://180.211.94.12:1802/..) but the error says something about localhost, is this a Default error when the Connection cannot be established??

Comment: You can try 127.0.0.1 It is for the device (emulator) itself.

Comment: have you tried your Ip and your port?? dnt write "localhost" in your AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS

Comment: I didnt use localhost anywhere, only the error Returns "localhost..."I dont give a port number, only: 'String AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS = "h ttp://myserver.com/folder/";' and then 'url = new URL(AUTHENTICATION_SERVER_ADDRESS);'

Comment: it could not access your LAN.just adding the IP of the server on your LAN allowed you to access it from the emulator. :)

Comment: have you added the permission INTERNET